# How to verify pre/post conditions in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I am new to dafny. I am trying out some examples to get a better understanding.

Here is the code sample that I have written so far,
**EDIT:** https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/6mOt
I am not sure how to full fill these pre/post conditions. I tried something but didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to provide a more concrete question or show some effort of implementing those loops, before we can help you.

How do we know this is not an assignment?

Comment: @MatthiasSchlaipfer: ok, now i have updated the code snippet. I also want to know is there are some array resizing in-built functions available in dafny? or the only way is to create a new instance?

Comment: No, such a function is not available right now. One can of course implement a helper method, maybe just an `{:extern}` method stub for such a library method which is already built into one of Dafny's target-languages adding pre-/post-conditions would be a good choice.

Who knows, maybe at some point one will be added to https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dafny will not infer any invariants, so you'll need to add them. Especially if you know the post-condition already and your loop is at the end of your method it is easier to find it. Sometimes simply replacing the length of the array you're iterating over by the loop counter is enough. Then, at the end of the loop, when `i >= n`, you can think of the invariant turning into the post-condition.

In your case, it got me far, but needed a bit of tweaking. One of the invariants that you need to add is

`invariant forall j : int :: 0 <= j < i && j < m ==> cells[j] == copy[j]`

I leave the other one for you.